# AndroidManifest.xml issue: "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED" error

Tags: java, android, xml, configuration, mobile-development

I'm currently working on an Android project, and I've encountered an error while trying to install my app. The error message I'm receiving is:

> "The application could not be installed:
> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED."

I've checked my AndroidManifest.xml file, but I can't seem to find the issue causing this error. Here's my AndroidManifest.xml for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.portlmedia.streets">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:banner="@drawable/banner"
        >
        <activity android:name="com.portlmedia.streets.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.portlmedia.streets.MainActivity"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:lockTaskMode="if_whitelisted"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.DAYDREAM" />
                <data android:scheme="googlechrome" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="about" />
                <data android:scheme="javascript" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have reviewed the file for any obvious issues, but I'm unable to identify the source of the error. Can someone please help me pinpoint the problem and provide guidance on how to resolve this "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED" error?

I attempted to upgrade my Android app to Android 12 but encountered "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED" error in my manifest file.

```
compileSdkVersion 31
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.portlmedia.streets"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    buildConfigField "String", "WEBVIEW_URL", "\"https://streets.portlmedia.com\""
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't make the mistake ad think the `AndroidManifest.xml` you have in your project is the one included in your APK. Every library can add additional entries to `AndroidManifest.xml` in the build process. So you have to look at the final version, not the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the following attribute within your app's AndroidManifest.xml file for any components that have `<activity>, <activity-alias>,<service>, or <receiver>` components declared:

```
android:exported="true"
```

**Your intent-filter doesn't have this**

Reference [Link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

Comment: I set android:exported="true" for the activities that are designated as entry points (<intent-filter> with "MAIN" and "LAUNCHER" categories),